# php: how to get POST value from the form, when the variable name is not known before the page loads?

Tags: php, post

main.php files has:

```
$randnum=rand(100,500);
echo '
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="my.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="A'.$randnum.'" id="A'.$randnum.'" value="catch me!">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
';
```

browser displays:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="my.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="A382" id="A382" value="catch me!">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

How to catch "catch me!" from the form ($_POST['A382'] value)? (382 is not defined before the page was loaded). Any way to get an array of all variables that are send by POST method? Any better way?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to use AJAX to submit the data to the server.

Comment: `Any way to get an array of all variables that are send by POST method?` - That's what `$_POST` contains... It's an array of all the data submitted.

Comment: if you want just the keys, you can use `array_keys($_POST)`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a Submit button (just added). No AJAX should be used for this purpose. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
    if(substr($key,0,1) == 'A')
    {
        $number = intval(substr($key, 1, 3)); //Number from A***
        if($number)
            $data = $value; //Value of field A***
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply loop through each of the variables:

using foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    echo $key . ' : ' . $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider instead of making the random number part of the variable name, you make the variable an array, such as

```
<input type="text" name="A['$randnum']" id="A'.$randnum.'" value="catch me!">
```

Then, you DO know the name of the variable and you just need to loop through the $_POST['A'] array for the key/values.

Comment: You are probably right, but (at least) it doesn't work for big numbers in a range [100000,5000000] -  it will take a lot of time to find just a value.